# using objects names (like panels) from an array of strings

Tags: java, string, object

I am trying to run some objects methods in this way:

```
  String[] sequencer = {"seq1", "seq2", "seq3", "seq4", "seq5", "seq6", "seq7", "seq8"};
  for(int i; i<9; i++) {
      sequencer[i].setBackground(Color.red);
  }
```

seq1, seq2..seq8 are jPanels. Any idea how to do this ? I hope you understand what I want to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you do this? Or are you looking for something else?

```
    JPanel []  sequencer = new JPanel[]{seq1, seq2, seq3, seq4, seq, seq6, seq7, seq8};
    for(int i; i<9; i++) {
       sequencer [i].setBackground(Color.red);
    }
```

Comment: This makes sense. I've added the jpanel visual way. Is there any method to add them to an array ?

Comment: I don't believe there is a method. If you were using an ArrayList instead, you could do something like `List <JPanel> sequencer = new ArrayList<JPanel>(); sequencer.add(seq1);` But I'm not sure that's what you are looking for.

Comment: I will try with your suggestion. Thanks!